# How will a bad grade from a somewhat unrelated course look on applications?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, undergraduate, biology

I'm taking a second year genetics course as a math major (I was interested in bioinformatics, and I need genetics for that). I'm doing poorly in the course so far (I'm passing, but not with great marks). I was wondering how a bad grad will look on my application to math grad schools.

My current cgpa is about 3.8 so I'm wondering if I should just cancel this course (honestly, bioinformatics isn't even interesting to me anymore) and take a CAN on my transcript than a bad grade that will kill my cgpa. How would that look?

Any and all help is appreciated!